I want to reduce air speed without backpressure
I am setting up a test-bed for an experiment. Here's what I have.

A circular car exhaust
The gas comes out of the exhaust at a velocity, x.
We need to lower the gas velocity to x/3

Conditions

The 'reducer' should exert very less backpressure on the flow

What possible directions should I look into? If you know any pre-filters, baffles, geometries that can help me reduce the flow rate in minimum size, that'd be awesome. I don't want any kind of flow-controller device, just a basic architectural setup.

increase the diameter.

An expansion nozzle, here's an illustration: -<

@GregLocock lol

to u/solarmike 's comment, velocity is volumetric flow rate divided by area.

The question asks to reduce the Flow Rate, which is impossible afaik, without changing the system concept (catching some mass, or chemical reactions, etc). If we're talking about the exit velocity, then a feasible solution is to increase exit area (mass flow rate = rhoUA) as Solar Mike points out.
